# Node.js request.js HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN

Tags: node.js, http

I got desperate about one problem and I need some help...
I'm using node.js to crawl a list of websites, some of them gives me this error, for example:
http://www.fz-juelich.de/portal/DE/Home/home_node.html, Parse Error, HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN

```
request.get({
    url: uri,
    timeout: timeout,
    headers: {
        referer: domain
    }
}, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error)
        console.log(error);
    console.log(body);
});
```

though, curl -i --raw http://www.fz-juelich.de/portal/DE/Home/home_node.html
works just perfect

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
JSESSIONID=E594677A6CCA13BE0338E1D00A729C34; Path=/cae:
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: de
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E594677A6CCA13BE0338E1D00A729C34; Path=/
Content-Length: 19677

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
```

Also I'm able to see this website in my chrome browser

Any ideas in which side should I dig to get rid of this errors?

Comment: No ideas?... I start thinking about using some 3rd party C++/C extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the end of this journey I no longer use node.js for crawling and parsing

Go lang crawler fits much better here, more flixibility in http library and easier to write really concurrent stuff

Comment: Yes, Node is very picky about HTTP Headers - I had the identical issue mentioned above. The source website was sending a Link header with HTML inside which was crashing Node. To get around it I wrote a separate script which cURLed the data I needed then called that from my Node scripts

Comment: I also struggled with this problem but insisted on using Node. Fortunately I found a lib `node-libcurl` which does a fantastic job and is also backed by Insomnia (free alternative to Postman) so it will be around for a while :)

Answer (score 1):

I use quotes in properties and that resolve for me :

```
request.post(url,{
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic onEnAGrosEncodedBase64',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    form: {
      'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }
 })
```

I hope that can help someone ;)